# Select2 event after ajax replace

Tags: ajax, jquery-select2

I'm trying to create filters using a Select2 dropdown and I do not know why the Select2:select event stop working after updating the html with the data that comes via Ajax.

Please help - My PHP is:

```
<div class="select-yellow fecha-container">
    <select id="fecha" class="select2 fecha-addon" data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity">
        <?php foreach($fechas as $fecha): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>"><?php echo formatDate($fecha); ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

The JS file:

```
$('#fecha').on("select2:select", function(e) {

    // here it's working

    var fecha = $('#fecha').val();
    var provincia = $('#provincia').val();

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: app.base_url + "/ajax-gallery/",
        method: "GET",
        data: {
            provincia: provincia,
            fecha: fecha,
            tag: provincia

        },
        dataType: "html"
    });


    request.done(function (msg) {

        if($.trim(msg).length) {
            $('.gallery-container').html(msg);

            var $filter = $('.gallery-container').find('.fecha-addon');
            $('.fecha-container').html($filter);

            $("#fecha option").each(function(){
                if($(this).val()==fecha){
                    $(this).attr("selected","selected");
                }
            });

            $('#fecha').select2({
                minimumResultsForSearch: -1
            });

            //after rebind the event doesn't work

        }else{
            $('#gallery-notices').html('<strong>No hay más imagenes con esta fecha</strong>');
        }
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    });



});
```